# Can I reset column layout in TFS?

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2013, in the Backlog view, I change the columns to be displayed, the order and the size, with the "Column options" button. It works fine.

But later, I modify that for all users by editing process file (using witadmin command). Now, all users but me have the same layout.

How can I reset my layout to have the default one too ?

Comment: I don't think there is one. You'll need to setup the board manually to match the others.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have customized your view, TFS has a record squirreled away in its bowels saying, "Hey, this person has a custom view, ignore the default in the process file."

There is no way via the web interface (or Visual Studio) to get rid of that and default back to the default.

If you have access to the DB backing your TFS installation, you can look through the schema and figure out which records represent the customizations you have made and delete those.

That's about it really.